# How to improve Face matching time

Tags: python, performance, time, face-recognition

I'm working on a project that aims to detect each person's face while entering to a public space and store *entering time* and the *person's image* (array format) in Elasticsearch, and then detect each exiting  face, loop over the Elasticsearch index relative to people who have entered in that day, pass to my model two images (detected exiting face and faces stored in Elasticsearch), match the two faces and return enter time, exit time and total duration.

For face matching/Face re-identification I'm using a VGG model that takes ~1sec to compare two faces.
This model takes two parameters and returns a value between 0 and 1.
I loop over all faces, I append accuracy to a list, and the appropriate face is which has the minimum value returned.
So that, if I have 100 entered person in that day, while looping to find one face, the program will take more than 100sec, but in my use case the program needs to run in real-time.

Any propositions for that ?

This is a Screenshot of my code where I'm calling the model:
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of code/text

Answer (score 0):

In case you have too many image I would suggest to look at method like -[FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). It is more efficient than computing distances between the new and other saved images. Also, you can try with 4-layer Conv net/efficient-net instead of VGG(but need to check accuracy degradation). As VGG is more computationally expensive.
Another approach you can do if list of person is fixed then you can save the embedding of all saved images and store them. At real time you can use feature extractor to extract feature and compare it with all stored embedding, this will definitely save time for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Rambo_john - here is a nice [image search demo](https://www.pinecone.io/docs/examples/image-similarity-search/) that uses VGG and a managed Faiss service.